# Matlab push button to continue

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

Inside my main function I call a function that need to do some stuff before continue the program and I want to add a push button that allows to continue if the results are correct or start again the function to redo the calculations.
I tried in this way adding the first button that allows to continue the program

```
h1  = figure(1);
% plot stuff...
button = uicontrol('Parent', h1,'Style','pushbutton',...
         'Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1],...
         'String','Display Difference',...
         'Callback',@button_callback);

function button_callback(hObject,eventdata)
    if get(hObject,'Value') == 0
        %do nothing
    else
        return
    end
end
```

But doesn't work because the program continues also without push it.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell Matlab to stop and wait for user's input.
You can do that using the [`uiwait` command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiwait.html)

So the code would be (even if I did not test it):

```
h1  = figure(1);
% plot stuff...
button = uicontrol('Parent', h1,'Style','pushbutton',...
         'Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1],...
         'String','Display Difference',...
         'Callback',@button_callback);
uiwait(h1);

function button_callback(hObject,eventdata)
    if get(hObject,'Value') == 0
        %do nothing
    else
        uiresume;
        return
    end
end
```

In Matlab there are also [predefined dialog box](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/predefined-dialog-boxes.html) that you can use for this purpose.

Comment: Yes I was using `questdlg` to have the same result  but your solution works. Thanks